# Azure blob copy with python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, blob, azure-blob-storage

I need to create, upload and copy 100 blobs from one account storage to second with python script.

`

```
  import os, uuid
  from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__


#connect_str1 = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING1')
connect_str2 ="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=arielstorageaccount2;AccountKey=n+Bx[...]Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
#blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_service_client2 = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str2)

# Create a unique name for the container
#container_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
container_name2 = str(uuid.uuid4())

# Create the container
#container_client = blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)
container_client2 = blob_service_client2.create_container(container_name2)


local_path = r"C:\Users\pavel\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\data"
os.mkdir(local_path)

    # Create a file in the local data directory to upload and download
for i in range(100):
    local_file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
    upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print(cwd)
    # Write text to the file
    file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
    file.write("Hello, World!")
    file.close()

    # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
    blob_client = blob_service_client2.get_blob_client(container=container_name2, blob=local_file_name)

    print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)

    # Upload the created file
    with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

`

I have a few problems :
1. It does create new containers but not upload BLOBS
2. The code doesn't do the loop 100 times
3. don't understand how to copy the BLOB from one account storage to another

Comment: `The code doesn't do the loop 100 times` - How many times does it loop? Do you see files created locally?

Comment: 1 time , yes locally  I see them.

Answer (score 1):

try with this code ,I tried in my system ,I tried with downloading all the blobs from container to local machine  then  uploading them to another storage

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os
source_key = 'source_key'
source_account_name = 'sourceaccounttest1'
block_blob_service = BlobServiceClient(
    account_url=f'https://{source_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/', credential=source_key)

des_key = 'des_accKey'
des_account_name = 'desaccount'
des_blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
    account_url=f'https://{des_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/', credential=des_key)
#generator = block_blob_service.list_containers("testcopy")
source_container_client = block_blob_service.get_container_client(
    'testcopy')
des_container_client = des_blob_service_client.get_container_client(
    'testcopy')
generator =source_container_client.list_blobs("")

fp = open('local file path', 'ab')
i=1
for blob in generator:

    print(blob.name)
    print("HI")
    path_to_file = "localfilepath"+str(i)+".txt" 
    
    blob_client = source_container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    with open(path_to_file, "wb") as my_blob:
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
        blob_data.readinto(my_blob)
    i=i+1
    
path_remove = "C:\\"
local_path = "C:\\blobs" #the local folder
i=1
for r,d,f in os.walk(local_path):
        if f:
            for file in f:
                file_path_on_azure = os.path.join(r,file).replace(path_remove,"")
                file_path_on_local = os.path.join(r,file)
                file_names='doc'+str(i)
                blob_client = des_container_client.get_blob_client(file_names)
                i=i+1
                
                print(blob_client.blob_name)
                with open(file_path_on_local,'rb') as data:
                    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Locally saved inside blob folder

[image]

[image]